# kube-api server high cpu

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I want to know how I can check why one of my ctrl node and kubernetes consumes more cpu than the others.

I have a cluster with 3 ctrl nodes and 4 worker nodes.

I have an nginx load balancer with the least_conn algorithm to distribute the requests to the ctrl nodes.

Monitoring the resources with the top command, I observe that of the three ctrl nodes, the kube api server process always in the first ctrl node gives me a cpu usage above 100%, unlike the other ctrl nodes where the kube-api server uses less than 20%.

I want to know why?

And how can I see that same representation of consumption, be it pod, containers. nodes in grafana

Answer (score 0):

After finding what happens in your cluster using `kubctl top node` and `kubectl top pod`, you can further diagnose what is happening with `kubectl logs $pod -c $container` on the pod.

At this point, it is up to the container to provide information on what it is doing, so ideally, you would collect metrics in the pods to get a quick insight into what is happening on your cluster using e.g. Grafana. You can also have a look at the resources assigned to your pod using `kubectl get pod $pod -o jsonpath='{.spec.containers[].resources}'`.

In your case, the log messages of the kubernetes apiserver should give you a hint. Probably, something (another container/pod maybe) is clogging up your API server.